# Перегрузка операторов Python, неявное использование repr для методов ведёт к RecursionError

Tags: python-3.x, ооп, перегрузка-операторов

Доброго времени суток, при изучении перегрузки операторов в Python столкнулся с одной проблемой.Если в классе реализовать перегрузку оператора **repr**,то (по неясной мне причине) он начинает использоваться не только для самого класса, но и для вывода метода этого класса.Прошу объяснить, почему так происходит.

```
class Exmp:
    def __repr__(self):
        print("Вызван repr")
        return "%s"% self.ise
    def __init__(self):
        self.name="spam"
    def ise(self):
        print("something")
```

Если написать подобный код в интерактивной оболочке, создать экземпляр класса `x=Exmp()` и далее написать  `x.ise`или же `x`, то почему-то запускается repr, реализованный в классе Exmp, хотя x.ise является методом, и как мне кажется для него должен выполняться repr из класса method. Кроме того, я не могу понять почему вдруг запускается рекурсивный алгоритм.

```
x=Exmp()
print(x.ise)
```

ведёт к [ошибке](https://repl.it/NBv1/3):

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: Попытка вывода `x` в интерактивной оболочке - это и есть вывод `repr` объекта. `x.ise` - это не вызов метода. Вызов метода - это `x.ise()`.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, x.ise - это объект связного метода экземпляра.

Comment: https://repl.it/NBv1/3 Я не могу понять из-за чего появляется рекурсия и почему вызывается repr класса Exmp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё очень просто.

По шагам:

Срабатывает строчка `print(x.ise)`

Поскольку не указано скобок после `x.ise`, то результатом этого выражения будет не результат его выполнения, а просто сам объект метода ise, связанного с объектом x.

Чтобы вывести его на экран питон использует обычный repr для метода объекта, и результат этого репра обычно (если ничего не переопределять) выглядит как-то так:

`<bound method Exmp.ise of <Exmp object at 0x7fa235a159e8>>`

Обратите внимание на правую часть, которая во внутренних треугольных скобка. Здесь питон пишет, к какому объекту привязан метод. И для этого, что логично, вызывает repr этого объекта!

А поскольку вы repr объекта переопределили, то используется именно переопределённый метод. В котором у вас есть строка

`return "%s"% self.ise`

Питон пытается подставить в строку self.ise. Но, поскольку здесь тоже нет скобок, в качестве строкового значения для self.ise используется не какое-то возвращаемое значение, а тупо repr для метода self.ise. И интерпретатору опять-таки необходимо понять, как написать объект, к которому прикреплён метод. И интерпретатор опять дёргает repr объекта x. А для его выполнения опять нужно определить строковое представление для self.ise...

Comment: Огромное спасибо за подробный ответ!